# Access JWT payload variables (tuupola in Slim Framework)

Tags: php, jwt, slim

I am successfully authenticating my users against my API using Slim Framework 4.
I do so using a middle ware that looks like this:

```
$app->add(new \Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([

    "algorithm" => ["HS512"],
    "logger" => $logger,
    "secret" => getenv('JWT_SECRET'),
    "rules" => [
        new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication\RequestPathRule([
            "path" => "/v2"
        ])
    ]
]));
```

This works like a breeze except one thing. The payload contains a string that I need to pass to the database so I need to read the token in the API when it is sent back to the API (It is in the http headers).

How could I automatically set a PHP variable that contains the string coming from the payload?

The token arrives back to the API in the Authorization header.

The payload when sent back to the API looks like this:

```
{
  "jti": "1PD0vKUwqlBocToxmZgeJA",
  "iat": 1580575309,
  "exp": 1580577109,
  "stk": "KsdL5WxiGkYIkFeduiQkMR8nTwOZ56ik"
}
```

I am interrested in accessing the value of "stk" :)

I am not an advanced PHP developer so please forgive me if my question is a bit simple.

Thanks a lot in advance for your precious answers.

Answer (score 0):

So,

The answer is [Here](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth#attribute).

It is passed as a attribute and easily accessed as any attribute later on.